# How to collect data from several input boxes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am creating a Polymer application in which search button has several inputs from input boxes. And from that collection of that input boxes search button should perform search operation considering all inputs.

following is the image for scenario -
[image: search panel]

{ iron-form } is one of  the option for that but I want something new and with ease. 
Please help me.

Comment: Mind displaying your HTML?

Comment: Test out my answer. I tried to create a script that will most likely work on your page (dependent on whether or not you have the specified elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your **HTML**, so I'm just going to be using elements which I think you will have within your `document`.

Test this out:

**Pure JavaScript**:

```
var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];

form.onsubmit = function(){ // on form submit
    var input = document.querySelectorAll("input");

    for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){ // loop through each input on the page
        alert(input[i].value); // will alert the value of the input
    }

    return false; // stop form from posting
}
```

**jQuery**:

```
$("form").submit(function(){ // on form submit
    $("input").each(function(){ // foreach input
        var value = $(this).val(); // grab its value

        alert(value); // output its value
    });

    return false; // prevent form from posting
});
```

So when the form submits, it will iterate through each `input`, and output each value through an `alert`.

Hope this helps! :-)

Comment: @Anky tell me how it goes for you! :-) also, if it worked; please consider selecting this as fixed your problem

Comment: Thanks @Caelan, its work for me, Good work. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this with the Polymer tag there is also a Polymer `iron-form` specific way to handle this. @Caelan is correct but this will not work with Polymer elements (or custom elements). Examples of these elements are `paper-input` and`paper-checkbox`. See [Paper Elements](https://elements.polymer-project.org/browse?package=paper-elements) for a list of all customized inputs.

`<iron-form></iron-form` comes with a property method `serialize` and `validate` which you can use to collect all inputs (including custom elements) in one function call.

See [iron-form.serialize documentation](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-form#method-serialize)

```
var form = document.querySelector('iron-form')

form.onsubmit = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = form.serialize()
    // Do something with data
    // return false; // could use instead of event.preventDefault()
}
```

See [preventDefault vs return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false) thread on stack overflow both will work in your case since you do not care about bubbling events.

Comment: thanks @costrouc, I will try this too. But above is also working with polymer element <iron-form>.